# Firebase python cloud function is unable to import local package

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I try to deploy a firebase cloud function via Firebase cli.
My folder structure is:

```
functions
|--localpackage
|  |-__init__.py
|  |-constants.py
|-main.py
|-requirements.txt
```

An I try to import `constants.py` via `from localpackage.constants import *`. I guess thats the way it's supposed to work. Source https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?hl=de&gen=2nd#python-preview_3 refers to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python?hl=de.

Problem:
As soon as i want to deploy the function via `firebase deploy --only functions`, i get the error:

```
    from localpackage.constants import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'localpackage'
```

Local test deploy via `functions-framework --target testPy --debug` works just fine.

I tried to change paths and import statements but nothing worked.

Comment: Make sure that your local package `localpackage` and the main script `main.py` are in the same directory. [Directory Structure](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python?hl=de#:~:text=myfunction/%0A%E2%94%9C%E2%94%80%E2%94%80%20main.py%0A%E2%94%94%E2%94%80%E2%94%80%20localpackage/%0A%20%20%20%20%E2%94%9C%E2%94%80%E2%94%80%20__init__.py%0A%20%20%20%20%E2%94%94%E2%94%80%E2%94%80%20script.py)

Comment: What is inside `constants.py`. You are not importing the file, you are trying to import `constants` from the file.

Comment: There is no class in it, just constants like `ERROR_STATUS  = -1`. And I thought that the package could not be found. Also `import localpackage` does not work either. Is it possible that these files are somehow not getting copied ( or sth. ) somehow? Because running it locally works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that was [patched and merged to main](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/pull/12) last week but not yet pushed out to PyPi.

If you prefer not to reference the github repo in your dependencies, here's the work-around:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.as_posix())

from test import base
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefix a dot to the module name which signifies a local module:

```
from .localpackage.constants import *
```

Comment: This results in `from .localpackage.constants import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. :/

Comment: This worked! Would be great to have some additional explanation on why this does actually work and what is happening by default (without the `.`)

Comment: @Luponius The current directory is not in the path. Adding . (dot) means use the current directory. See PEP 328 for more details: https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for the clarification and very interesting read!  Puts this into perspective.